# W3C validation error with image width

Tags: html, css

I need an image to resize to the full width of my webpage. This works fine with the following HTML/CSS:

```css
#logo{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%"></div>
```

However W3C validation picks this up as an error. "Bad value 100% for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw % instead."

I tried this alternative, but now the image does not resize of course:

```
<div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" width:100%;></div>
```

How do I retain the same effect while still passing the W3C validation? It is the only error on my entire page, and I know it doesn't really matter, but there is bound to be a solution I am overlooking.

Comment: It should be `<div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%"></div>`

Comment: This doesn't solve the validation issue?

Comment: Related: consider using CSS units "vw" and "vh" `100vh` (for viewport width) equals the width of the screen. `100vh` equals the height of the screen (not of the page).

Comment: I do use "vw" and "vh" for resizing other objects in conjunction with @media queries - but I couldn't find a simple way for these objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kindly use the following code in order for you to have W3C validation

```
<div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" width="100%" /></div>
```

(OR)

```
<div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:100%;" /></div>
```

Comment: <div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:100%;" /></div> works fine, thanks.

Comment: width with percentage is not a valid w3c standard. Also please avoid to use inline styles as much as possible

Answer (score 3):

Because width attributes does not use % it uses digits like `width='100'`, means 100px. if you want to apply 100% width on image, use CSS

```
#logo img {
   width: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading w3school official documentation

> In HTML 4.01, the width could be defined in pixels or in % of the containing element

but also

> In HTML5, the value must be in pixels.

So you can't specify a valid width in percentage for `HTML5`, tryo to use `style="width:100%"`

Comment: w3scools is a very bad idea to get authentic documentation, as it horribly invalid in many cases. i.e. the the answer you posted.